# Using Poetry as build backend how can I perform Cythonization and Build Process?

Tags: python, build, python-packaging, cythonize

I'm trying to cythonize my code using Poetry as the build backend, and I want to ensure that the Cythonization process is included when I create a build using the poetry build command. I'm aiming to achieve this without directly using a setup.py file. Could anyone provide me with an end-to-end process or guidance on how to achieve this?

It would be extremely helpful if you could provide code snippets or configuration examples that demonstrate the integration of Cython with Poetry for build processes. Also, I don't want to use the old process of invoking setup.py using setuptools as it is kind of deprecated.

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Here's what I'm looking for:

- How to set up my project to work with Cython and Poetry.
- How to configure Poetry to run the Cythonization process during the build.
- What changes do I need to make to my project structure or configuration files to ensure the Cythonization process is part of the build process triggered by poetry build?
- Steps or configuration changes needed in the pyproject.toml and other relevant files.
- Any example code snippets or project structures that showcase this integration effectively.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.